# LwIP Netconn API - Check if TCP communication was completed

Tags: embedded, rtos, lwip

I'm currently working on creating tests for specific use cases one of which is Init WF200 -> connect to AP -> send TCP data -> Deinit WF200. The application is very energy critical so I have to ensure that the WF200 is enabled as short as possible.
The hardware I use is a EFM32GG11 MCU together with a WF200 WIFI transceiver, both from SiliconLabs. I'm using an RTOS and the lwip stack with the netconn API for TCP communication.

The problem is that I can't find a way to know if the TCP transaction was completed, which I need to know before putting the WF200 into shutdown. Currently the task is faster then the actual transmission which leads to data loss and incomplete TCP communication.

Currently I have a working work around which is adding a delay. But that doesn't seem like an elegant solution to me, especially because the delay is dependent on the amount of data being sent.

I have already tried checking the tcp pcb state but with no success. Is there some way I can block the thread until the transaction is completed?

Thanks in advance!

```
static void tcp_thread(void *p_arg) {
    struct netconn *conn;
    err_t err;
    LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(p_arg);
    // needed, otherwise netconn_connect fails
    KAL_Dly(1);
    conn = netconn_new(NETCONN_TCP);
    if (conn != NULL) {
        struct ip4_addr broker_ip;
        IP_ADDR4(&broker_ip, SERVER_IP_0, SERVER_IP_1, SERVER_IP_2, SERVER_IP_3);
        err = netconn_connect(conn, &broker_ip, 65432);
        if (err == ERR_OK) {
            // NOCOPY only safe when data is static and const
            err = netconn_write(conn, test_data, strlen(test_data), NETCONN_NOCOPY);
            printf("Data sent\n");
            netconn_close(conn);
            netconn_delete(conn);
        } else {
            printf("No TCP connection\n");
        }
    } else {
        printf("No netconn\n");
    }
    KAL_Dly(200);
    sl_wfx_deinit();
    OSTaskDel(0, &err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

netconn will execute a call back, you can add while(1){osDelay(2);} to your code and wait for that callback to finish. Maybe post a flag in the callback you can check for. For example you can use that data RX callback (or error callback, etc), inspect for an ack, then write to a var you can check in your code's while loop.

Comment: Please format your answer better. Please have a read of the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve the formatting in your answer.